# How to resolve linking error?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, conditional-compilation

I hav a project.it shows error only with linking only.

it displays __getch alresdy defined evnthough i hav ignored specific library MSVCR80D.dll it shows error.

Plz Help me in this regard.....

after using /verbose:

```
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:msvcprtd
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCMRTD
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSCOREE
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:atlsd.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:ole32.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:shell32.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:oleaut32.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:shlwapi.lib
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:ws2_32.lib
Referenced in config.lib(configwrapper.obj)
        Loaded msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) already defined in ACEsd.lib(Log_Record.obj)
      Found "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (__imp_?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializetransport_settings.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializeretentionsettings.obj)
        Referenced in s2libs.lib(operatingsystem.obj)
        Referenced in s2libs.lib(errormajor.obj)

        Loaded msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in ACEsd.lib(Log_Record.obj)
      Found "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializetransport_settings.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializeretentionsettings.obj)
        Referenced in s2libs.lib(operatingsystem.obj)
        Referenced in s2libs.lib(errormajor.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializereplicationpairsettings.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializecdpsnapshotrequest.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializeatconfigmanagersettings.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializeretentioninformation.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(marshal.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(serializevolumegroupsettings.obj)
        Referenced in config.lib(unmarshal.obj)
```

Comment: did you name a function getch? Can you show some code?

Comment: Tht may sound harsh, but the straightest way to resolve is to to set the "Show Progress" to "all" in the linker settings and then just analyze the output.

Comment: There's no error message in that output.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the project settings , at Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library.

the setting , whether it MD , MTD or whatever, must be compatible between your library and ACE's library.

you should not manually ignore any library, there should be no need for that.

Comment: Instead of 'compatible', I would have said 'the same'...  Is there a case where you can mix up libraries not compiled with the same setting?